# groovy script to read properties file from multiple repositories in Github

Tags: github, groovy

I have this Scenario wherein I have to connect to multiple repositories in github and extract properties file of individual projects.

Comment: Where are you facing problem? reading property file?

Comment: I am facing problems while connecting to github

Comment: Basically i am using github rest api v3..but i don't know how to use that api in groovy to read a particular property file